# FB.Login not working in Opera Mobile

Tags: facebook, opera

I have a mobile web site using Facebook Connect to authenticate user. I encountered a problem login with Opera Mobile. I have below javascript to detect login status, but only in Opera Mobile the callback is not firing. Is anyone encountered this problem?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxx',
            channelUrl: 'http://xxxx/channel.html',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
    };

function handleStatusChange(response) { // --> NOT FIRE
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //Login, show Logout button
    }
    else {
        //Show Login button

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera Mobile has new release today (12.10.ADR-1210081231). It solved the Facebook login issue, but there is a minor issue. The Facebook windows will not close automatically after user login.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you put the JS tags and other required HTML in a logical order (if you use an fb-root element put the scripts after it, try putting them inside BODY if they are currently in HEAD). I've seen FB login fail because the tags were in the wrong order, and because some browsers do "speculative parsing" this cause of random cross-browser malfunction may not be immediately obvious. (Besides, you create a race condition that might break in any browser if the network has a hiccup and the timing of loading stuff is unexpected..)

If you still have problems it would be useful to get a link or a demo to look at. We've tested a random page that uses FB Connect and worked fine. Apart from tag order issues I can't guess what might go wrong for you here.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to rearrange the order as what you mentioned.

Comment: Hi hallvors, i have tried your suggestion but no luck. This happen with Facebook official sample as well. It won't able to login with opera mobile. www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/